# Using Batch, Take certain words and move them to a new line

Tags: batch-file, replace

I need a Batch script that can take this text file:

```
Set Date=2015-10-20 Set Time=18:05:47.47 Set Ipw=%ipwan% Set loc=%Location% Set Img=%ImgName%.bmp
```

And turn it into This:

```
Set Date=2015-10-20 
Set Time=18:05:47.47 
Set Ipw=%ipwan% 
Set loc=%Location% 
Set Img=%ImgName%.bmp
```

Any Ideas? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a variable with CR+LF
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set NL=%%a^
%Empty line 1/2%
%Empty line 2/2%

rem Read the line from file
set /P "line=" < file.txt

rem Change " Set" by "CR+LF+Set"
echo %line: Set=!NL!Set%> file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-10 delims= " %%A IN (file.txt) do (
     echo %%A %%B
     echo %%C %%D
     echo %%E %%F
     echo %%G %%H
)>newfile.txt
```